Unable to use a custom ValueResolver
I'm developing a Symfony 7 REST API. I'm following the official docs to implement a custom argument resolver to handle mapping of the request payload format that my endpoints are receiving to DTOs (https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/value_resolver.html#adding-a-custom-value-resolver).
Here's an example of a request payload to an endpoint
{
  "article": {
    "title": "How to train your dragon",
    "description": "Ever wonder how?",
    "body": "You have to believe"
  }
}

Here's the custom ValueResolver
class NestedJsonValueResolver implements ValueResolverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly SerializerInterface $serializer,
        private readonly ValidatorInterface $validator,
    ) {
    }

    public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): iterable
    {
        $argumentType = $argument->getType();

        if (!in_array('NestedJsonDtoInterface', class_implements($argumentType))) {
            return [];
        }

        return [$this->mapRequestPayload($request, $argumentType)];
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param class-string<NestedJsonDtoInterface> $type
     */
    private function mapRequestPayload(Request $request, string $type): ?object
    {
        if (null === $format = $request->getContentTypeFormat()) {
            throw new HttpException(Response::HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE, 'Unsupported format.');
        }

        if ('' === $data = $request->getContent()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            $nestedJsonObjectKey = $type::getNestedJsonObjectKey();

            $decodedData = json_decode($data, true);
            $nestedJsonObject = $decodedData[$nestedJsonObjectKey];

            $payload = $this->serializer->deserialize($nestedJsonObject, $type, 'json');

            $violations = $this->validator->validate($payload);

            if ($violations->count() > 0) {
                throw new HttpException(Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, implode("\n", array_map(static fn ($e) => $e->getMessage(), iterator_to_array($violations))), new ValidationFailedException($payload, $violations));
            }

            return $payload;
        } catch (UnsupportedFormatException $e) {
            throw new HttpException(Response::HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE, sprintf('Unsupported format: "%s".', $format), $e);
        } catch (NotEncodableValueException $e) {
            throw new HttpException(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, sprintf('Request payload contains invalid "%s" data.', $format), $e);
        }
    }
}

Here's my services.yaml
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    App\ValueResolver\NestedJsonValueResolver:
        tags:
            - controller.argument_value_resolver:
                  name: nested_json
                  priority: 150

Here's the controller action
    #[Route('', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function store(
        #[ValueResolver('nested_json')]
        StoreArticleDto $dto
    ): JsonResponse
    {
        $article = $this->articleService->store($dto);

        return $this->json([
            'article' => $article,
        ], 201);
    }

And here's the target DTO
final readonly class StoreArticleDto implements NestedJsonDtoInterface
{
    private const NESTED_JSON_OBJECT_KEY = 'article';

    public function __construct(
        #[Assert\NotNull]
        #[Assert\Type('string')]
        private ?string $title,

        #[Assert\NotNull]
        #[Assert\Type('string')]
        private ?string $body,

        #[Assert\NotNull]
        #[Assert\Type('string')]
        private ?string $description,
    )
    {
    }

    public static function getNestedJsonObjectKey(): string
    {
        return self::NESTED_JSON_OBJECT_KEY;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getBody(): ?string
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}

Upon hitting an endpoint the following Exception is being thrown.

How should I go about making the custom ValueResolver work?

What is the signature of the store() method in the article service?

@Cyclonecode It's public function store(StoreArticleDto $dto): Article

You should use either a debugger or tricks that enable debugging. Then follow the execution path along the resolver and see which if statements work. If you can't use a debugger then I would suggest using file_put_contents('debug.log', 'xxx' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND) where xxx is the line/place identifier. You can see debug.log in the root of the project.

What is the purpose of using these nested DTOs? Do you plan adding other properties to it or is it just redundant nesting?
My point is, if you don't need to nest, don't nest. The route specifies clearly, which entity are you working with. If you dropped the nesting and made the format like this:
{
  "title": "How to train your dragon",
  "description": "Ever wonder how?",
  "body": "You have to believe"
}

You could use the framework native #[MapRequestPayload] attribute that solves the mapping into DTO and handles validation. You could drop your custom resolver and not worry about maintaining extra code. The controller would look like
    #[Route('', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function store(
        #[MapRequestPayload]
        StoreArticleDto $dto
    ): JsonResponse
    {
        $article = $this->articleService->store($dto);

        return $this->json([
            'article' => $article,
        ], 201);
    }

If you need the nesting, you could solve this by nesting the StoreArticleDto in another DTO StoreArticleRequest and this would enable you to add properties in the future while keeping #[MapRequestPayload] attribute.
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class StoreArticleRequest
{
    #[Assert\NotNull]
    private StoreArticleDto $article;

    public function getArticle(): StoreArticleDto
    {
        return $this->article;
    }

    public function setArticle(StoreArticleDto $article): void
    {
        $this->article = $article;
    }
}

In the controller you would simply deserialize into the StoreArticleRequest
    #[Route('', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function store(
        #[MapRequestPayload]
        StoreArticleRequest $dto
    ): JsonResponse
    {
        $article = $this->articleService->store($dto->article);

        return $this->json([
            'article' => $article,
        ], 201);
    }

Anyways, I recommend using the standard #[MapRequestPayload] attribute over a custom one any day of the week. It is a feature introduced in 6.3 and since you are using 7.0 it is fine. JUst make sure you installed the symfony/serializer-pack and symfony/validator to work properly.

Thank you for your answer. I'm aware of the native MapRequestPayload attribute, the thing is that I'm implementing a backend based on those specs (https://realworld-docs.netlify.app/docs/specs/backend-specs/endpoints) which clearly state that the format of the payload is a nested object. I've thought about another dto that would contain the target dto but it seemed kind of clunky to me. The request dto pattern you've suggested does not look that bad so I think I'll look into it. Again, thanks for your input.

@Max No problem. I know, how much hassle it is to maintain extra code that server such a critical purpose as this. Prior to 6.3 I used to have a custom ParamConverter that did just that. There were several edge cases and limitations, tied to this implementation. I think that you will be better off just creating a request DTO and using a native mapping solution.  Anyways good luck moving forward with your backend :)

If anyone would still be interested in the root of the problem, I've recently found it. The NestedJsonValueResolver class is actually behaving properly and returning an empty array in the resolve method because the class_implements function returns a strings array of fully qualified class names of the interfaces it implements and I've been checking for the existence of an unqualified class name.
Here's the correct implementation of the resolve method.
public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): iterable
{
    $argumentType = $argument->getType();

    if (!in_array(NestedJsonDtoInterface::class, class_implements($argumentType))) {
        return [];
    }

    return [$this->mapRequestPayload($request, $argumentType)];
}

In the previous implementation upon returning no resolved value the exception was being thrown as there indeed was no default value provided for the controller method parameter.
